# Lighttpd - configure multiple PHP versions

Tags: centos, php, lighttpd

I have 2 php fpm services in my server, one is php 5.6 in port 9001, and the other is php 7.2 in port 9072.

I have a website that is running on PHP 5.6, working using the following config:

```
fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
        ((
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => "9001",
                "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
        ))
)
```

I want a subdomain to work with php 72, currently it configured like that:

```
###### Subdomain settings ##############
$HTTP["host"]  == "dev.mydomain.net"{
        server.document-root = "/var/www/lighttpd/dev"
}
```

but when I add:

`server.port = "9072"`

my lighttpd service fail to start after restart.

Any idea what could have gone wrong? My logs say nothing about it.

```
2020-04-15 10:31:23: (server.c.1521) server started (lighttpd/1.4.54) 
2020-04-15 10:31:23: (server.c.1550) WARNING: unknown config-key: alias.url (ignored)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure lighttpd to run multiple fastcgi servers and to send traffic to one or the other based on conditions.

```
fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
        ((
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => "9001",
                "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
        ))
)

$HTTP["host"]  == "dev.mydomain.net"{
        server.document-root = "/var/www/lighttpd/dev"
        fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
                ((
                        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                        "port" => "9072",
                        "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
                ))
        )
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but this is not working either. Web server stay down without any log

Comment: @TheUnreal please triple check what you are doing.  Then check again.  If lighttpd doesn't start, it produces trace why it doesn't start.  (authoritative source: I am a lighttpd developer).  You need to find the log.  You can manually run `lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` to run the config in pre-flight test mode.  Run that as the same user that starts lighttpd and look at the output.  If you still have `server.port = "9072"` then remove that from your config.  It's broken syntax and lighttpd will complain.